# Update froala toolbar icons dynamically

Tags: angular, toolbar, froala

In my `angular` application I have a drop down and a `froala` editor below that. Based on the selection of the drop down, the toolbar icons of the froala editor should be updated. Please see the code below

**froala.component.html**

```
        <select  [(ngModel)]="selectedType" (change)="customizeEditorButtons()" > 
         <option value="1"> Option 1 </option> 
         <option value="2"> Option 2 </option> 
        </select>


<textarea [froalaEditor]="editorOptions" [(froalaModel)]="froalaContent"></textarea>
```

**froala.component.ts**

```
this.editorOptions = {
   toolbarButtons: this.toolBarbuttonsModified
}

 public customizeEditorButtons(){
  this.toolBarbuttonsModified = [ 'redo' , '-', 'bold', 'italic'];
}
```

The `customizeEditorButtons()` function won't update the froala editor as it is already rendered on init. So what is the option to update the toolbar icons dyanamically.

Answer (score -1):

I have found the solution for this. On change of the drop down, destroy the current instance and initialize it again with new tool bar buttons.

```
public customizeEditorButtons(initControls){
  initControls.destroy();
  this.toolBarbuttonsModified = [ 'redo' , '-', 'bold', 'italic'];
  initControls.initialize();
}
```

Also the initialization should be manual.